# MySQL PDO Check if email exists

Tags: mysql, pdo, rowcount

So I'm stumped on why the function I've made to check if an email already exists in my database doesn't work...maybe someone here can help me! No matter what I do, it returns false and I cannot figure out why. This function below is within a file named classes.php. Yes classes.php is included within activate.php along with the file holding the DB connection code.

```
    public function emailExists($email) {
        $query = $this->db->prepare('SELECT `email` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = ?');
        $query->bindValue(1, $email);
        try {
            $query->execute();
            if ($query->fetchColumn() === 1) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            die ($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

This next bit of code is within a file named activate.php

```
    $email = $_GET['email']; // Gets email from URL
    if ($users->emailExists($email) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Sorry, that email address doesn\'t exist.';
    }
```

Comment: Try: if ($query->fetchColumn() == $email)

Comment: ^ Why the heck did I not think of that LOL. That fixed it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
public string PDOStatement::fetchColumn ([ int $column_number = 0 ] )
```

it returns a string so you cannot use the type equality operator
use the equality operator or castto integer

Answer (score 0):

fetchColumn returns a string:

```
    if ($query->fetchColumn() == $email) {
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns the `email`, which I assume to be the email address you also pass as a parameter. You check if it returns `1`. That's what's going wrong. Change the query to

```
SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE `email` = ?
```

Even then, you need to change

```
if ($query->fetchColumn() === 1) {
```

to

```
if ($query->fetchColumn() === '1') {
```

since fetchColumn returns a string.

Comment: This works as well! Would you suggest this method over this?

        if ($query->fetchColumn() == $email) {
            return true;
        }

Comment: Same difference. Theoretically my query will be faster, but that is so theoretical that it probably won't be measurable. Also, I like the strict (`===`) operator where possible, but you could also use it when comparing to `$email`, since that is a string as well. Either solution will do, and there are others as well. Have your pick. :)

Comment: Thank you for your time and fast reply. I've learned something new, and you helped me get this issue sorted out which I greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

In documentation of [fetchColumn](http://php.net/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) is:

> Returns a single column from the next row of a result set or FALSE if there are no more rows.

You check against wrong value in the condition. Better would be:

```
if ($query->fetchColumn() !== false) {
```